# Update component before actionListener finish

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I have a dialog, when user press the button 'Accept' I want to show a ProgressBar in the same dialog, but this its update when actionListener finish.

```
<p:dialog id="dlgGenerarLista" modal="true" height="180" width="500" header="Generar Lista de Trabajo" widgetVar="dlgGenerarLista">
    <p:commandButton onclick="PF('dlgGenerarLista').hide();" value="Cancel" />
    <p:commandButton id="btnAceptarGenerar" value="Accept"
    actionListener="#{crearEstrategiaBeans.GenerarListaTrabajo}"
    oncomplete="PF('dlgGenerarLista').hide();"update="basic"/> 
    <p:panel id="basic" widgetVar="basic">                 
        <p:progressBar rendered="#{crearEstrategiaBeans.visibilidadBarraProgreso}" id="progressBarIndeterminate"  mode="indeterminate"/>
    </p:panel>   
</p:dialog>
```

In the method *GenerarListaTrabajo()* I say that *visibilidadBarraProgreso = "true"* , so I want that in that moment it shows the progressBar. The progresBar it show when all the process finish.

Comment: Sorry, I have a hard time understanding your problem. This might be caused by me not  being a native English speaker. but also by your English. Maybe you can use something like Google translate to get things clear.

Comment: @Kukeltje "I have a dialog which has a progressBar with render false, and when I press the OK button, I change the status to true to show it, but it is displayed only when the actionListener is finished and I want it to be displayed at the moment of pressing."

Comment: uhhh.... if the rendered attribute of the progressbar is false and you only update the surrounding panel in the update attribute of the commandbutton, that is excactly what you tell it to do. Don't use the rendered attribute but make it visible with some css.

Comment: @Kukeltje But in the method in the actionListener I change to true the attribute of the progressbar, but I understand what you say with CSS. I'll try, thanks :)

Comment: the update is **always**  processed after the action/listener. That is how it just works. It cannot update during execution.

Comment: @Kukeltje with CSS it works perdect. Thanks :)

Comment: Please create and answer with your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working solution for your problem:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:commandButton onstart="PF('progressBar').jq.show();" oncomplete="PF('progressBar').jq.hide();" />
    <p:progressBar widgetVar="progressBar" style="display: none;" />
</h:form>
```

Short explanation: With PF('progressBar') you'll get the PrimeFaces JavaScript object for your progressbar. With jq you'll get the jQuery element for the progressbar. Then you can use jQuery methods show and hide.

Comment: That's all? Thanks, its work perfect and its a simple solution.